# Toggling a React embed widget onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have an embeddable widget built with React that works like what Intercom.io has, however I want the widget to be opened with a button in the host website and closed by a close button in the application.

I don't know if there's an efficient way to do this that follows best practices.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    const triggerBtn = document.getElementById("btn-trigger");
    // let show = false;
    triggerBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      embed.init();
    });
</script>
```

App entry

```
export const init = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
};
```

App.js

```
  toggleChat() {
    this.setState({
      visible: !this.state.visible
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <footer>
        {this.state.visible ? (
          <ChatUiContainer
            messages={this.state.messages}
            addAction={this.addAction}
            showForm={this.state.showForm}
            submitForm={this.submitForm}
            loading={this.state.loading}
            submitMessage={this.submitMessage}
            show={config.show}
            toggleChat={this.toggleChat}
          />
        ) : null}
      </footer>
    );
  }
```

Comment: This question is very broad. Could you include the code you have tried so far?

Comment: provide your code..

Comment: I'll include my code but before I do, let me provide some clarity to my question. There is an existing website that includes a button which is supposed to initialise the react application. The react application on the other hand has a close button to to close the application.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems the way to do it. I had a similar requirement, I'll list down my approach. You can adopt it if it seems elegant to you.

1. Declaring a javascript class and have a embed function within it. `MyClass.embedWidget(widgetName,'divToEmbedIn')`
2. This function called different functions, fetched the required data and then populated the component using `ReactDOM.render(<WidgetName />,divToEmbedIn);`
3. Left the rest of the functionality for the user itself. That is he/she must define when the component must be embedded. `MyClass` would just embed the widget where you want it.

Though your approach and mine may look the same, but there is a slight difference. In your case, you can embed only one widget because the `init` logic is defined in your app entry point. (You can still define different `ReactDOM.render()` functions but i guess that wouldn't look nice) But if that is your requirement, then that's okay.

This approach will slightly give you the functionality to embed different components in a more controlled way.

Hope this clears out things for you.

Comment: Thanks Aseem. You are right, your approach is way more efficient than mine but for my use case(a single messaging app within an existing website), I don't think I will need to go through all of those steps. 

However, I am afraid I don't see how this fixes my main problem of toggling the chat window with a button on the host non-react website and closing the app from within the chat window itself. I'll try and create a codepen with a demo of what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: I thought you already achieved that. Maybe your question wasn't clear or i misunderstood it. Nevertheless, a codepen will be best. I'll see if I can help you with that